# AWS: Could not able to give s3 access via s3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am the root user of my account and i created one new user and trying to give access to s3 via s3 bucket policy:

Here is my policy details :-

```
{  "Id": "Policy1542998309644",  "Version": "2012-10-17",  "Statement": [    {      "Sid": "Stmt1542998308012",      "Action": [        "s3:ListBucket"      ],      "Effect": "Allow",      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket-demo-1",      "Principal": {        "AWS": [          "arn:aws:iam::213171387512:user/Dave"        ]      }    }  ]}
```

in IAM  i have not given any access to the new user. I want to provide him access to s3 via s3 bucket policy. Actually i would like to achieve this : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/   But not from IAM , I want to use only s3 bucket policy.

Comment: i want to give s3 console access to user via s3 bucket policy.Is it not possible to give s3 console access with s3 policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following AWS blog post (the blog shows IAM policy, but it can be adapted to a bucket policy):

- [How can I grant a user Amazon S3 console access to only a certain bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/)

you can make the following bucket policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1589632516440",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1589632482887",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket-demo-1",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::213171387512:user/Dave"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1589632515136",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-bucket-demo-1/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::213171387512:user/Dave"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This will **require** user to url directly to the bucket:

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/aws-bucket-demo-1/
```

The reason is that the user does not have permissions to list all buckets available. Thus he/she has to go directly to the one you specify.

Obviously the IAM user needs to have `AWS Management Console access` enabled when you create him/her in the IAM service. With `Programmatic access` only, IAM users can't use console and no bucket policy can change that.

Comment: What is the change that we need to do in above policy to work for s3 bucket. i dont want to use IAM in my case. Could you please let me know is there any way ?

Comment: @Johnney I already made the change in the policy provided. This is bucket policy adapted from IAM policy in the blog post.

Comment: Hi Marcin, Yes, i have given consol access to the user while creating in IAM. I have copied all your bucket policy with my s3 bucket details. But still the user is getting permission denied in UI while accessing s3 bucket. Note:- I am giving access user in same account. Some sources for s3 ACL says we can give access to users only in other AWS account. That wont applicable for policies right ?

Comment: @Johnney Double check your details and make sure the user is using direct url to the bucket. I tested this policy on my example bucket with an example IAM user, and it worked for me. Maybe there is something else preventing your user from accessing it? ACL is needed here, unless you don't own the objects in the bucket.

Comment: it works with URL you mentioned. But how do i list all buckets if we want?

Comment: @Johnney glad to hear. For listing buckets more permissions are needed (s3:ListAllMyBuckets, s3:GetBucketLocation, and s3:ListBucket), see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html). But they have to go to IAM user, not bucket policy, because bucket policy applies to only one specific bucket.

Comment: Ohh okay.. It means there is no way of listing all buckets via s3 bucket policy. Only from IAM we can achieve that right?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [ListBuckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-buckets.html).

It seems like you want this user to only be able to see your bucket but not access anything in it.